# How to find the asymptotic eigendecomposition of matrix with big-O?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics

How to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following real symmetric matrix that depends on a real variable $t > 0$ with $t\rightarrow 0$?

$$
A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & O(t^2) \\ O(t^2) & at^2 + O(t^3) \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a$ is a real constant, and $O(\cdot)$ is the big-O notation